# Change the 3e item with php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a small project and got stuck.

In my database are some items with an ID and a NAME. With some php i get the information to my webpage.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE active = 'yes'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
         echo "<input type='number' class='res-menu-pick' 
         placeholder='".$row[1]."' name='".$row[0]."' min='0' max='16'>";
}
```

This works perfect but there is one problem..
all my items are printed on one row.. What i want is 3 item per row.

Now:

= = = = = = = =

What i want:

= = = 
= = = 
= =

I've tried to use some css ->

```
.res-menu-pick:nth-child:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this problem? I can't just change the css of my input, because then it will change on all my inputs.

Thanks,

Comment: Try to add "<br/>" or other html balise to format your result in your echo (input in a "div" for example): `echo  : "<input type='number' class='res-menu-pick'  placeholder='".$row[1]."' name='".$row[0]."' min='0' max='16'><br/>";`

Comment: add `echo "<br/>";` inside your loop, but only every 3rd iteration (you'll have to keep a counter). Or abandon the idea of such a rigid layout and use responsive divs so that it scales to the size of the client's device / browser window and displays as many items in one row as will fit (you could still limit it to 3 max, if you wanted).

Comment: That won't work, <br> will be the same as display: block;

I want only the 3e (6e, 9e etc) to go tho the second line.

Comment: Which is why I said "only every 3rd iteration"

Comment: Oh ! Just add a var php as "counter" and every time it's a multiple of 3 you add a <br/>

Comment: That works ya, but when i need to make it responsive the items need to get 2 a row. Don't know if i can check the devicewidth with php?

Comment: @Loxiuras no, PHP can't do that because it runs on the server - at that point no browser is involved. Instead you'd generate HTML which doesn't directly control the layout (e.g. using div instead of br) and use CSS (probably with media queries) to make it responsive. This is a broad topic if you're not familiar with it, but there are a huge number of tutorials and samples online showing how to do this kind of thing. Lots of pre-built code frameworks are available for free too which can make building a responsive site a lot easier and quicker. Search round for something which suits you.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE active = 'yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<input type='number' class='res-menu-pick' 
    placeholder='".$row[1]."' name='".$row[0]."' min='0' max='16'>";

    if (count == 3) {
        echo "<br />";
        count = 1;
    } 
    else {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Work yah!
Thought maybe there is a css fix.

Tried everything with nth-child(3) but didn't work.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Should works with `if (($count % 3) == 0)` as condition too, no? (and without the else and the count restart). Just to know, I don't often use the modulo operator !

Comment: Well you can use the modulo but a modulo is a expensive operation. I don't know what he wants but you can use the modulo if it's a small script

Comment: That works ya, but when i need to make it responsive the items need to get 2 a row. Don't know if i can check the devicewidth with php?

Comment: Well you can send the device width or place them in a div and maybe use bootstrap for it?

Comment: You can read more about that at this website: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp